# Why the did the Alliance destroy the scuttled settler ship in Episode 3 of Firefly?

Tags: plot-explanation, firefly

I just watched episode 3 of *Firefly* and during a conversation between the Alliance ship's Commander and Captain Mal, the Commander tells him that Serenity will be auctioned.

However, at the end of the episode the Alliance just destroyed the ship that contained the rescued settlers' cargo.

Why wouldn't they just keep that ship and auction it like they were planning to do with the Serenity?

It was established earlier that the ship had no mechanical issues, so for sure it should hold some value.

Comment: Because fascists are funny like that?

Comment: Possibly, they didn't care one way or the other, and the Commander was saying what he thought would be most painful/objectionable to Mal - someone ELSE in HIS ship, and the Alliance profiting from it.

Comment: Thought so, but seems the commander was a good government employee, and as such they tend to follow these bureaucratic procedures - I'd imagine that captured ships wouldn't be destroyed right away unless it had some serious issue

Comment: @Luciano Have you seen the movie *Serenity*?

Comment: No, I'm still following the series for now and will watch the movie after that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was the ship that was hit by Reavers right? I think they blew it up because a) superstition and b) fear (maybe  there was another survivor on there). The Reavers edge on a source of mythological terror in the series, so I would have serious doubts if anyone from the Alliance ship would have set foot on the derelict.